# How to send pandas dataframe in python mail

Tags: python, pandas, html-email

I am trying to send pandas table in python mail.i tried but can't get the result.also convert pandas dataframe to html 
here is my code.
please help

> code

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
import pandas as pd


def sendMail(ID,NAME,MARKS):
    dict = {'ID': ID, 'NAME':NAME, 'MARKS': MARKS}
    da = pd.DataFrame(dict)
    df=da.to_html()


    try:
        email = "EMAIL@gmail.COM"
        password = 'PASSWORD'
        send_to_email =["EMAIL@gmail.COM",]
        subject = 'Critical Incident'
        messageHTML = '{df}'
        messagePlain = 'marks of your class'
        print(messageHTML)
        msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
        msg['From'] = email
        msg['To'] = ', '.join(send_to_email)
        msg['Subject'] = subject

        msg.attach(MIMEText(messagePlain, 'plain'))
        msg.attach(MIMEText(messageHTML, 'html'))

        server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com",587)
        server.starttls()
        server.login(email, password)
        text = msg.as_string()
        server.sendmail(email, send_to_email, text)
        server.quit()
```

Comment: maybe consider sending that as text attachment to email?

Comment: how i can do it

Answer (score -2):

I found the answer

```
df=da.to_html()
ds=str(df)
messageHTML = 'marks'+ds
```